# How to find permanent Telegram file link?

Tags: telegram, cdn

I am trying crawl some channels data from Telegram web client. In this case some files of Telegram have links from `cdn` like this one:

```
https://cdn4.telesco.pe/file/SYmat3daXTqSHeIdhvRLnjetlwx4...
```

Because of Telegram security these links are not available permanently. I want to save images links permanently, does not matter from `cdn` or main server. How to change `cdn` links to main server links?

Comment: telegram doesn't provide permanent links.it's not a file hosting service.